# Nativescript Tabs not working when parent has tap event

Tags: ios, tabs, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have the following angular nativescript template.  I want to be able to dismiss the keyboard (from SearchBar) in Ios, so I added the often recommended dismissSoftInput() (inside hideKeyboard) when you tap anywhere else.  The problem is, once I add this, I can't select tabs, nor select any items within the child listviews.

What can I do to allow the top level (tap) while preserving the tab functionality?

```
<GridLayout rows="auto *" (tap)="hideKeyboard()">
    <GridLayout row="0" rows="*">
        <StackLayout row="0" class="input-field">
            <SearchBar #searchField hint="Search ..." class="input" (submit)="startSearch($event)" (clear)="startSearch($event)"></SearchBar>
        </StackLayout>
    </GridLayout>
    <GridLayout row="1" rows="*">
        <Tabs row="0"selectedIndex="0">
            <TabStrip>
                <TabStripItem>
                    <Label text="Tab 1"></Label>
                </TabStripItem>
                <TabStripItem>
                    <Label text="Tab 2"></Label>
                </TabStripItem>
            </TabStrip>
            <TabContentItem>
                <GridLayout rows="*">
                    <ActivityIndicator row="0" [busy]="isSearchingKJ"></ActivityIndicator>
                    <ListView row="0" *ngIf="kjResults?.length > 0" [items]="kjResults" (itemTap)="select($event)">
                        <ng-template let-item="item" let-i="index">
                            <StackLayout>
                                <Label class="search" [text]="item.book + ' ' + item.chapter + ':' + item.verse"></Label>
                                <Label class="search-results" textWrap="true">
                                    <FormattedString>
                                        <Span *ngIf="item.text.length > 0" [text]="item.text[0].text"></Span>
                                    </FormattedString>
                                </Label>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ng-template>
                    </ListView>
                </GridLayout>
            </TabContentItem>
            <TabContentItem>
                <GridLayout rows="*">
                    <ActivityIndicator row="0" [busy]="isSearchingMormon"></ActivityIndicator>
                    <ListView row="0" *ngIf="mormonResults?.length > 0" [items]="mormonResults" (itemTap)="select($event)">
                        <ng-template let-item="item" let-i="index">
                            <StackLayout>
                                <Label class="search" [text]="item.book + ' ' + item.chapter + ':' + item.verse"></Label>
                                <Label class="search-results" textWrap="true">
                                    <FormattedString>
                                        <Span *ngIf="item.text.length > 0" [text]="item.text[0].text"></Span>
                                    </FormattedString>
                                </Label>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ng-template>
                    </ListView>
                </GridLayout>
            </TabContentItem>
        </Tabs>
    </GridLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

Comment: Looks like not an issue with NativeScript but [MDCTabBar](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios/issues/5777) itself.

Comment: Is there any other way to allow the user to hide their keyboard without carrying out a search?

Comment: The issue here is not hiding keyboard but just the tap event on the parent. You could still try adding listeners on each tab content and hide keyboard.

Comment: If I put it on the tab content, I lose the list view item tap event